# How to align a long title in a table of content so that it won't be over page numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

I'm trying to change the alignment of the TOC of this document in order to make a long title, which occupies more than one line, to break to the next line before they are vertically aligned to the page numbers. This is how it looks:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor............................... 22
```

But I want it to be like this (first line is supposed to be justified):

```
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit  amet, consectetur  adipiscing 
elit sed do eiusmod tempor ..........................22
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Changing the right spacing also moves the page numbers.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you manually insert a line-break [Shift-Enter] where you want it? Downside, of course, is that if you repaginate or change text you've got to do it again.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't work. The line break still makes the upper line justified and with the same length, so it just increases the space between words.

I'm thinking the best solution is making the text aligned to the left. It does what I want as long as the line isn't as long as the available space, but it will work, for my cases.

Comment: Could you please let me know if you could solve this issue?

Comment: @ebrahimi I'm sorry but it's been such a long time, I don't remember if I solved it or how. The answer below though thus seem to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible.  You have to manually edit the ***indentation*** and ***tab*** rules for the TOC style that you want to modify.

1. Open the **Styles** pane.
2. *Right-click* the style that you want to modify.
3. Click **Modify...**
4. Click the **Format >> Paragraph...**
5. In the *Indentation* section change the **Right** indentation level to the position where you want the text to wrap to the next line.
6. Click the **Tabs...** button.
7. Enter a tab stop at the position where you want the page number to be right-aligned (past the indentation position that you just set).
8. Set the **Alignment** to right.
9. Set the desired **Leader** character. (optional)
10. Click **Add**.
11. You may need to remove the previous tab position by selecting it from the list and clicking **Clear**.
12. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text. Right click. Select 'paragraph'. Put in values of indentation (say 0.5"). This will solve your problem.

Comment: And will it also place the page number at the desired position?

Comment: I tried it myself on a TOC I made. The 'paragraph' formatting doesn't touch the page number. So it works.

Answer (score 0):

For recent Microsoft (mine is Microsoft 365) there's a feature name distribute (Ctrl+shift+J) for more precise text distribution.

[image]